# How do I get an edit button to work for a table view in xcode?

Tags: xcode, tableview, edit

I've recently completed the apple tutorial on table views called Bird Watching and this worked fine. However, i'm now trying to take it further by adding an edit button and seem to be having a problem.

Below is the code that the MasterViewController uses to create my table. This works fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BirdSightingCell";

static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
if(formatter == nil){
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
}
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell textLabel]setText:sightingAtIndex.name];
[[cell detailTextLabel]setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)sightingAtIndex.date]];
return cell;
}
```

I've tried using some of this code in order to get the edit button working and below is what I created. This doesn't work and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}
}
```

One of the error messages I've had states "No visible @interface for BirdSightingDataController declares the selector removeObjectAtIndex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up the *Bird Watching* tutorial on the Apple website, to know exactly what you're talking about and which classes the objects are an instance of.

In your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method, you try to remove a certain object. When removing an object, you have to make sure it's deleted from both your view (in this case your table view) and your model object (in this case your data controller). Your removed the row from your table view like this:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This part looks good. However, you try to remove the object from your data controller using the following line of code:

```
BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You sent the `removeObjectAtIndex:` method to `self.dataController`. The `removeObjectAtIndex:` method can only be sent to an instance of `NSMutableArray`. Your data controller is an instance of `BirdSightingDataController`, which is not an `NSMutableArray`. Thus, after trying to send the `removeObjectAtIndex:` method to `self.dataController`, you got an error.

To access the object at a certain index of your data controller array, you declared and implemented the `objectInListAtIndex:` method like this:

```
- (BirdSighting *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex {
    return [self.masterBirdSightingList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}
```

Now you want to remove the object at a certain index of your data controller array, you could declare a method like `removeObjectInListAtIndex:` in your `BirdSightingDataController` header file as well. You can then implement it like this:

```
- (void)removeObjectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex {
    [self.masterBirdSightingList removeObjectAtIndex:theIndex];
}
```

Note that this method doesn't return anything, as it just removes an object from the array. Make sure you use `- (void)` instead of `- (BirdSighting *)` in both your header and implementation file.

Now, instead of sending the `removeObjectAtIndex:` method to your data controller, you can simple remove the object (which the user deletes) from your data controller like this:

```
[self.dataController removeObjectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is all baffling to me as I'm pretty new to this. How would I carry out these suggestions?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time in helping me. Just tried the above and managed to get the delete button working. Thanks again.